# how can I customize auto generated django form?

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I've created a form on Django app with its builtin forms class.

here is my **forms.py** file.

```
 # import form class from django
from dataclasses import field
from django import forms

from .models import #MYMODEL#

class myForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = #MYMODEL#
        fields = "__all__"
```

and my view function in **views.py**

```
def index(request):
    context = {}

    form = myForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
    
    context['form'] = form
    return render(request, "index.html", context)
```

and finally the page *(index.html)* that shows the form

```
    <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <input type="submit" value="Kaydet">
    </form>
```

So, what I need to do is **to set custom input types** like text or select box since the auto-generated form includes only text inputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`Widgets`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/forms/widgets/).

This is an example:

```
   class myForm(forms.ModelForm):
        class Meta:
            model = #MYMODEL#
            fields = "__all__"
            widgets = {            
                'category': forms.Select(attrs={"class": "form-control"}),
                'title': forms.TextInput(attrs={"class": "form-control"}),          
                'description': forms.Textarea(attrs={"class": "form-control"}),            
            }
```